# How to count how many times two words occur in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file, text, count

I have a text file called dogs.txt with the following lines.

> '#'color     body     fur     type
>
> white     large    hard     conservative
>
> yellow    large    hard     conservative
>
> brown     large    soft     violent
>
> yellow    large    soft     conservative
>
> brown     small    hard     conservative
>
> brown     small    hard     conservative
>
> white     small    hard     conservative
>
> yellow    small    soft     violent
>
> yellow    small    hard     violent
>
> brown     large    hard     conservative
>
> white     large    soft     conservative
>
> yellow    small    soft     violent
>
> brown     small    soft     conservative
>
> brown     large    hard     violent
>
> brown     small    hard     conservative
>
> yellow    small    hard     violent

Each line represents a dog. There are two things I want the output to show when the person input dogs.txt.

1. How many dogs are there? Check
2. How many dogs are yellow and violent?

The output will tell you there are 16 dogs.

What I need to do next is find how many of this 16 dogs are yellow and violent. I been stuck on how to do this for a while. I'm thinking I will have to use infile.read() but I'm not sure how. Please help guys.

Comment: Are you using line.strip() to check if the line is empty?

Comment: @Adam Obeng yes I'm using line.strip() to check if the line is empty

Comment: The problem with your code is `num_yellow_and_violent =+1`. That `=+1` means "set the variable to the value `+1`. You want `+= 1`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks a lot. That was what was missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yellow_and_violent = 0    
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() and line[0]!='#':               
        lines+=1
    if ('yellow' in line) and ('violent' in line'):
        yellow_and_violent += 1
```

A few more things:

- rather than setting a variable to not analyse the file if it cannot be found, you could raise a custom Exception
- you should not use class names as variable names (e.g. `file`)

Which gives:

```
import os.path

filename = input("Enter name of input file >")
try:
    infile = open(filename, "r")
except IOError:
    raise Exception("Error opening file '%s', analysis will not continue" % filename)

dogs = 0
yellow_and_violent = 0

for line in infile:
    if line.strip() and line[0]!='#':               
        dogs += 1
    if ('yellow' in line) and ('violent' in line):
       yellow_and_violent += 1
print("Total dogs =",dogs)
print("Yellow and violent dogs = ", yellow_and_violent)
```

Comment: your yellow_and_violent answer give 0 everytime.

Comment: should be `yellow_and_violent += 1`, in second to last line. Also, you have an extra `'` at the end of your `if`

Comment: @nbrooks, thanks. This is why I don't like increment operators.

Comment: it is yellow_and_violent += 1 and I took the ' out but it still gives 16 dogs but it always prints 0 yellow and violent.

Comment: @Jett: There should only be one `for line in infile` loop, because once you've iterated through the file objects once, there are no lines left

Comment: @Adam Obeng Oh I see what your saying

Comment: @AdamObeng The thing is that now it only gives me 1 yellow and violent dogs when there are more. I'll update the program.

Comment: @Jett `num_yellow_and_violent =+1` should be `num_yellow_and_violent +=1`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way to check the number that are yellow and violent:

```
with open('dogs.txt') as f:
    f.readline() # Skip first line
    print sum({'yellow','violent'}.issubset(line.split()) for line in f)
```

However when I add the line number check it is not as elegant

```
with open('dogs.txt') as f:
    f.readline() # Skip first line
    i, num_dogs = 0, 0
    for line in f:
        num_dogs += {'yellow','violent'}.issubset(line.split())
        i += 1
    print i, num_dogs
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regexes:

```
import os.path
import sys 
import re
reg = re.compile("^yellow.*violent")
try:
    file=sys.argv[1]
    infile=open(file,"r")
except IOError:
      raise Exception("open '%s' failed" % filename)
lines=0
yv=0
for line in infile:
  if line.strip() and line[0]!='#':
    lines+=1
    if reg.match(line):
      yv+=1
print("Total dogs =",lines)
print("Total yv dogs =",yv)
```

Comment: @Kay, can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: The question is quite trivial. I would only recommend regexes as kind of last resort. This is not a problem where you should use regex …

Comment: why is that? are they slow?

Comment: I get an error using this program in   file=sys.argv[1] saying list index out of range

Comment: @Jett, yes you need to specify a filename: `python sc.py input`

Comment: Your program worked too but the reason I didn't picked you was because it was too complicated for my beginners level. You really know your python :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dog_counter = 0
yellow_and_violent = 0
with open('dog.txt', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        if line.startswith("'#'") or (not line.strip()):
            continue
        dog_counter += 1
        if ('yellow' in line) and ('violent' in line):
            yellow_and_violent += 1
print("Total dogs: %d" % dog_counter)
print("yellow and violent dogs: %d" % yellow_and_violent)
```